# Data stream not showing on iOS unless I hot refresh

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am creating a flutter application with firebase as the backend. I have a data stream that pulls data from a Firestore collection and presents it in Cupertino Picker after converting it to a list. The problem is that when I start the app and navigate to the page with the picker, the list is empty, unless I hot refresh. The data also shows when I pop context and land on the page with the picker, otherwise it is empty.

I get my stream like so:

```
  Stream<List<DataModel>> get myData {
    return myDataCollection.snapshots().map(_myDataListFromSnapshot);
  }
```

and map it to my model plus convert it to a list like so:

```
  List<DataModel> _myDataListFromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
    return snapshot.documents.map((doc) {
      return DataModel(
          name: doc.data['name'] ?? '',
          country: doc.data['country'] ?? '');
    }).toList();
  }
```

This is my picker:

```
return CupertinoPicker(
  useMagnifier: true,
  magnification: 1.1,
  squeeze: 2,
  backgroundColor: CupertinoColors.white,
  itemExtent: 50,
  onSelectedItemChanged: (int index) {},
  children: myData.map((myData) {
    return Text(
      myData.name + ' ' + myData.country,
    );
  }).toList(),
);
```

Is there anything I am not doing right. I will appreciate any assistance I can get. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `async` and `await`. The problem is that. Your method will look like this:

```
   Future<List<DataModel>> get myData async {
       return await myDataCollection.snapshots().map(_myDataListFromSnapshot);
       }
```

You can read more from [here](https://medium.com/@superman199323/3-errors-handling-of-flutter-dart-5406bf37ae03).

Comment: I tried this, I get the error: A value of type 'Stream<dynamic>' can't be returned from function 'myData'